# quaternions with python

Tags: ros, transforms, quaternion, rospy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently started using rospy after being working with roscpp. I wanted to reproduce this piece of C++ code:

```
geometry_msgs::Quaternion quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped goal;
goal.pose.orientation = quat;
```

For what I have found, the closest form would be something like:

```
quat = quaternion_to_msg(tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, th))
goal = PoseStamped()
goal.pose.orientation = quat
```

But this actually does not work because 'quaternion_from_euler' returns a four float array, instead of an object with {x, y, z, w} fields.

I have searched for some common function to do this easy transform, but I have not found it within the ros libraries. What I have seen is that many people make his own implementation:

```
def quaternion_to_msg(q):
  msg = Quaternion()
  msg.x = q[0]
  msg.y = q[1]
  msg.z = q[2]
  msg.w = q[3]
  return msg

goal.pose.orientation = quaternion_to_msg(quat)
```

Does ROS provide a common solution for this situation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12903/quaternions-with-python/) by [joan](https://answers.ros.org/users/881/joan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 245 on 2012-02-06

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Python has a nifty feature which allows you to expand a tuple into an argument list. Rather than setting all of the quaternion's fields individually, you can use the constructor as follows

```
q = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, th)
msg = Quaternion(*q)
```

This is equivalent to doing

```
q = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, th)
msg = Quaternion(q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3])
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [victorp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4163/victorp/) on 2013-03-18**:
Where can one find documentation on these mysterious functions ? http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/tf/html/python/ is quite... primitive.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-03-19**:
This is a python feature, not ROS. As such, it is documented in the python docs: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

**Comment by [victorp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4163/victorp/) on 2013-03-19**:
Thanks, but I mean about the `tf` python api.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-03-19**:
What do you mean? The tf api docs look pretty complete to me.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2014-01-05**:
Is there documentation for the tf.transformation module?